# Making columns into sort asc/desc in search api-based view

Tags: views, search

I've created a search page using Views and 'search api'. I've got my results showing in tabular format with the labels in a  above the results returned.

But I can't figure out how to make each label/column header a sort. I want the user to be able to click the label in the column header to then sort that column by ascending/descending.

Anyone know how to make that possible?

Comment: try using **Display: Table**.

Comment: You mean format: table? I'm using that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out. I have to set the field to 'string' in Search API configuration > index > edit. The default is 'fulltext', which sounds right, but isn't for this usage.

Then you have to change the settings for the format: table to make the field sortable.